# Exporting sheets as pdf error: Run-time error '1004'. We didn't find anything to print

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export all sheets in the workbook as separate pdf files using one button.

I followed a YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRZ6n3gHt3k

I get:

> Run-time error '1004'. We didn't find anything to print.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim folder_path As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "select the folder path"
    If .Show = -1 Then folder_path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, folder_path & 
    Application.PathSeparator & sh.Name & ".pdf"
Next

MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe there's a blank sheet in your workbook?

Comment: I see under "VBAProject (PERSONAL.XLSB) there is a microsoft excel objects tab. under that are 2 tabs labeled "Sheet1 (sheet1)" and "Thisworkbook"

Comment: I don't think PERSONAL.XLSB is the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Is your module under Personal.xlsb? If so, maybe that's causing the error, try to do it in your actual workbook "VBAProject(Name of the workbook for the macro)"

Comment: still the same error when i complete it in current workbook. could there be a general developer/macro setting i'm missing?

Comment: @BigBen the blank worksheet in the workbook was the problem, thank you!!!